# Add hours/minute to a datetime variable in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to add 30 minutes to my date time variable.

My code:

```
string time = ViewState["CloseTime"].ToString();
DateTime Closetime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Here my datetime variable is *Closetime*. I want to add 30 minute to it. How is it possible?

Comment: Did you check what methods are available for DateTime type ? You should be able to get idea from that.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask]. The first point is **Search, and research**. You show no research effort at all.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime x30MinsLater = currentTime.AddMinutes(30);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", currentTime, x30MinsLater));
```

Result:

```
4/11/2017 3:53:20 PM 4/11/2017 4:23:20 PM
```

Comment: Thanks @Rj Regalado

Answer (score 6):

Try `AddMinutes()`,

```
DateTime newDate = Closetime.AddMinutes(30);
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain.

Comment: This will not add thirty minutes to CloseTime. Look at the other answers.

Comment: Just told which method should be used. Thats why I started with "Try AddMinutes()". Anyway updated. @BentTranberg

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `CloseTime.AddMinutes(30);`. Make sure that this results in a new DateTime object.

```
var newTime = CloseTime.AddMinutes(30);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add 30 minutes to a DateTime variable, the following will work:

```
CloseTime = CloseTime.AddMinutes(30);
```

There are similar methods for adding seconds, hours, days, etc.

See here for the documentation: *[Methods for DateTime Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime#methods)*